# Alphabetical string arrays sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have posted previously and got some very helpful responses. I need to read in people's info (such as ID, age, etc.) from a text file into different arrays.
Records are like this
2012317109 Jamie Carles Smith Male 65 (different bits of info are separated by TAB, lines ending with newline)

However, regarding the ID numbers, I am told to use extraction operator (<<) to get the ID number as an integer and not as a string.

Then I must sort these records by alphabetical string order and then put these in an output file.

So far, I have the following. How should I proceed? I am not to use maps or vectors, I need to use arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void  selection_sort( double x[],  int  length)
{   
    int  i,  j,  k;
    double  t;

    for  (i=0;  i<length-1;  ++i)  {        
        k = i;       //find next smallest elm, x[k]

        for  (j=i+1;  j< length;  ++j)
            if  (x[k] > x[j])  k = j;

        //swap x[i] with x[k] 
        t = x[i];   x[i] = x[k];  x[k] = t;   
    }
}


int main () {

    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    fin.open("input.txt");
    fout.open("output.txt");

    if (fin.fail()) {
        cout << "Fail to open inout.txt" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    struct row{string ID, name, rest;};

    int x; 

    fout << x << endl;

    row *rows=new row[x];

    for (int i=0; i<x; ++i) {
        getline (fin, rows[i].ID,   '\t'); // ID
        getline (fin, rows[i].name, '\t'); // name
        getline (fin, rows[i].rest      ); 
    }

    selection_sort (row[], x); 
//complier error this line: expected primary expression before [ token.

}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use `operator >>` for extracting typed data from an  `istream` ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is probably to use `std::sort` (from the header `<algorithm>`), and define an

```
bool operator<(row const& lhs, row const& rhs)
{
    // delegates to operator< for std::string
    return lhs.name < rhs.name;
}
```

and then call the STL algorithm

```
// uses the above defined operator< for row objects
std::sort(rows, rows + x);
```

and then write the sorted output.

Comment: Thank you for the response. As I said I am a beginner and don't really have a clue about programming. So could you advise me about the additional steps in order to successfully insert these into the above code?

Comment: @user2273723 That type of question probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/